# Google maps android app shows gray grid tiles

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

this is the last code of project. i follow all of your steps 
https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435 but my app is stopped.

main.java

```
  package com.example.halkbank;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class GoogleMaps extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".GoogleMaps" >

 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

manifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.halkbank"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<permission android:name="com.example.halkbank.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.halkbank.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>


    <application

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 

            <activity
        android:name="com.example.halkbank.GoogleMaps"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google_maps" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

        <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="api key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and printscreens of my libraries

http://s22.postimg.org/66m62oxk1/image.png

what do you mean?? where is my mistake??

Answer (score 3):

Even though using a `MapView` with an older API key should still work, it has been recently deprecated. ([source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview))

You should be using the *Google Maps Android API v2* which is added to applications with a `MapFragment`. Read more about it in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Try adding the map to your application according to the tutorial in the documentation and then ask a new question if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use both version of the Google Maps API. While you are using the `android-support` library and `google-play-services` library that are required for `API V2` in you code you are using `API V1`.

I guess that this is the reason you don't see a map, you probably produces a key for `API V2` and trying to use in `API V1`.

The first thing you should do is to move your code to `API V2` as `API V1` as been already said is deprecated and outdated.

Now to be more clear this means that you will have to remove this:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

as it belongs to API V1.

Next you will have to get a new API V2 key, if you haven't already did so, you can use this guide to do this:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

and then change your java code from `MapActivity` and `MapView` code to a simple `Activity` or `FragmentActivty` and `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` respectivly depending for which platform you develop your application, you can get an idea how to start using this guide:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

You forgot to change the name of the activity in your manifest file from:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.halkmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

To:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.halkmaps.GoogleMaps"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Emil i sow your link and follow all this steps again, but on the end mobile give me alert that app has stopped :/

Comment: thanks a lot emil, pls see logcat above, i will be waiting for your answer :)

Comment: have you changed your code from API V1 to API V2? If so please post the new code as well.

Comment: sorry, this is from previous code. GoogleMaps is correct in my code, but error is same :/

Comment: try to set the name as:  android:name=".GoogleMaps" and clean you project and then try to run it again.

Comment: and remove this line:  android:name="com.example.halkmaps.GoogleMaps" as I already said.